# Why we don't have to set up libraries with JNI implementations in classpath anymore in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface, swt

I was reading The Definitive Guide To SWT and JFace which says that along with the SWT library we have to add the native library with JNI implementations in the classpath. I know we don't have to do this anymore to run an SWT application. But what is the reason. Is it already available in the classpath when we create a new project?

Comment: Have you tried running your application on a machine that doesn't have eclipse?

Comment: No. I think you did not get my point. When we create an SWT application, we have to add SWT jar in the class path exlpicitly. But we don't have to do this with the JNI lib as per I know because I have never had to do it. Earlier we used to add the JNI lib as well in the classpath exlicitly which the books states. So what's the reason that now we don't have to add the JNI lib in classpah anymore?

Comment: JNI libraries only have to in the Windows PATH, or the Linux LD_LIBRARY_PATH. And Windows will do an exhaustive search. Not every platform is the same. As I recall from yesterday, you're on Mac. Again, your new platform is different from other platforms. Perhaps you have a resource fork and don't even know it.

Comment: So how does the JNI library get in the Windows PATH, if we talk about windows? Also I have never ever had to add the JNI lib in windows too let alone Mac

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the plugin dependencies you will notice that there are bundles like `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64[...]`. These are the platform dependent fragments to the host-plugin `org.eclipse.swt[...]` which contain the JNI libraries for a given platform. A fragment provides the flexibility of extending the host-plugin at runtime.

For more information see:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_a_plug-in_fragment%3F
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseFragmentProject/article.html